# Can I include a for loop inside my print statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of winners of an event. I want to print them out at the end of my code, minus the brackets and quotes, and I am currently using:

```
            for items in winners:
                print(items)
```

Can I include this in a print statement?
I want:

```
            print("The winners of {} were: {} with a score of {}".format(sport, winners, max_result))
```

Is there a way of integrating the for loop into the print statement, or another way of eliminating the quotes and square brackets such that I can include it in the statement?

Thanks.

Comment: Please show an accurate sample of the data you are dealing with, and a sample of how you expect it to look like. Explain what is currently happening right now that is indicating to you that there is a problem with your code.

Comment: @idjaw This is a question about the capabilities of the language, not a question about a problem in code.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I don't see what is wrong with asking for more information in this case?Surely it must have been tried and something did not work out, which lead the OP to ask this question in the first place? Asking for more information to help the OP understand their mistake to me is a good approach here.

Answer (score 6):

You can't include a for loop but you can join your list of winners into a string.

```
winners = ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz']
print('the winners were {}.'.format(', '.join(winners)))
```

This would print

> the winners were Foo, Bar, Baz.

Answer (score 0):

If `winners` is a list of strings, you can concatenate them using `str.join`.

For example:

```
>>> winners = ['John', 'Jack', 'Jill']
>>> ', '.join(winners)
'John, Jack, Jill'
```

So you can put `', '.join(winners)` in your print call instead of `winners` and it will print the winners separated by commas.

Answer (score 0):

A for loop can only be supplied to `print` in the form of a comprehension.

But, if the list contents are in the respective order you require you can simply do:

```
print("The winners of {} were: {} with a score of {}".format(*winners))
```

This just matches each bracket with each item in the list. If you need to order this differently you just supply their relative position:

```
print("The winners of {1} were: {0} with a score of {2}".format(*winners))
```

Answer (score 0):

First note, in Python 3 `print` is a function, but it was a statement in Python 2. Also you can't use a `for` statement as an argument. 
Only such weird solution comes to my mind, which only looks like a for loop:

```
data = ['Hockey','Swiss', '3']
print("Sport is {}, winner is {}, score is {}".format(*( _ for _ in data )))
```

Of course, because `print` is a function, you can write your own function with all stuff you need, as an example:

```
def my_print(pattern, *data):
    print(pattern.format(*( _ for _ in data)))  

my_print("Sport is {}, winner is {}, score is {}", 'Hockey', 'Swiss', '3')
```

You can also read about **f-strings** ["Literal String Interpolation" PEP 498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/), which will be introduced in Python 3.6. This f-strings will provide a way to embed expressions inside string literals, using a minimal syntax.